# Как сравнить два списка с помощью linq?

Tags: c#, linq

Есть два списка

```
var lst1 = new List<string>(){"1","2","3"};
var lst2 = new List<string>(){"4","2","3"};
```

С помощью `Intersect` я вывожу те элементы которые повторяются однако хотелось бы узнать сколько раз повторяется каждый элемент.

```
var rez = lst1.Intersect(lst2); // тут результат 2 и 3
```

А хотелось бы так

```
var rez = lst1.Method(lst2)
```

2 встречается 2 раза
3 встречается 2 раза.

Comment: В пересечении, по идее, 2 и 3 встречаются _один_ раз. Если нужно 2 раза, возможно, речь идёт об объединении?

Answer (score 3):

Судя по всему, вам надо что-то такое:

```
var l1 = new[] { "котик", "котик", "слоник", "зайчик", "Бармалей" };
var mostOften =
    l1.GroupBy(s => s) // сгруппировали одинаковые строки
      .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()) // отсортировали по размеру группы
      .First() // самый большой размер у первой группы
      .First(); // берём из неё любой элемент (они все одинаковые)
Console.WriteLine(mostOften);
```

(выдаёт `котик`).

Если нужно самое частое в двух списках, просто сконкатенируйте их: `l1.Concat(l2).GroupBy(...`.

---

**Обновление**

Если вам нужен самый часто встречающийся элемент в *пересечении* всё не так просто. `Intersect` схлопывает повторы в списках. Поэтому правильный путь, судя по всему, такой:

```
var l1 = new[] { "зайчик", "котик", "котик", "слоник", "зайчик", "Бармалей", "зайчик" };
var l2 = new[] { "котик", "котик", "слоник", "зайчик", "Бармалей", "ёжик" };

// считаем, сколько раз каждый из элементов попадает в первый список
var firstCount =
    l1.GroupBy(s => s) // группируем одинаковые
      .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());

var result =
          // группируем одинаковые
    l2.GroupBy(s => s)
          // запоминаем значение и количество
      .Select(g => new { Value = g.First(), SecondCount = g.Count() })
          // убираем те, которых нет в первом списке
      .Where(vc => firstCount.ContainsKey(vc.Value))
          // заменяем количество на минимум из этого и предыдущего списков
      .Select(vc => new { vc.Value, Count = Math.Min(vc.SecondCount, firstCount[vc.Value]) })
          // сортируем по убыванию
      .OrderByDescending(vc => vc.Count)
          // первый элемент - с самым большим Count
      .First()
          // берём из него значение
      .Value;

Console.WriteLine(result);
```

(снова `котик`)

---

**Обновление**

Более изящное решение (подходящее под изменённое условие):

```
var lookup1 = l1.ToLookup(s => s);
var lookup2 = l2.ToLookup(s => s);
var result = l1.Intersect(l2)
               .ToDictionary(v => v, v => Math.Min(lookup1[v].Count(), lookup2[v].Count()));

foreach (var kv in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Item {kv.Key} occurs {kv.Value} times");
}
```

Comment: А почему не group + group join?

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Можно и так, но это уже ваше решение. Пишите!